# Ruby: generate input for JSON

Tags: json, ruby

I am passing input string and getting {} in target variable but i want to get ip and path
Below is my input string:

```
target = {:state=>"running", :id=>"12", :ip=>"1.1.1.1"}.merge({:path => "path", :type => "target"})
```

Below is my code:

```
class A
    def initialize(argv)
       target = JSON.parse(argv[0] || '{}', :symbolize_names => true)
       @address = target[:ip] 
       @path = target[:path]
    end
end
```

Please help!!!

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what's going wrong with the example you've provided. Please review How to Ask a Good Question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try again

Comment: can you include the line of code where you call `A.new`?

Comment: Agree. You have to totally different definitions for `target` in the example. If target is the merged hash passed as `argv[0]` then you don't need the `JSON.parse()` and your code will work as is `argv[0][:ip]`. If not, we need to know what `argv[0]` is

Comment: I mean "You have two..."

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so `JSON.parse()` requires a string for the first argument, a full string. 
When you do `argv[0]` you're simply grabbing the first element of the string so it's not going to work. 
I believe that in some cases `JSON.parse()` will return an empty hash when supplied a valid but non usable string which in your case is just a single character hence why `target` is only a `{}`.

So,  to fix I think, change  `argv[0]` to  `argv` and only supply a valid JSON string.

EDIT: Also just noticed, I think you're passing in a hash, which again won't work as `JSON.parse()` accepts a string not a hash, especially as `argv[0]` is pointing to a key value pair that doesn't exist as there is no key of `0` in your initial input hash.